# If i am getting 1 TB of data daily basis what would be my cluster size in hadoop

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, cloudera, hadoop2, cloudera-manager

Cloud era distribution Cloud computing Amazon Web Services What should be the EC2 type of instance

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely checkout Amazon Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) which is higher level service for managing and deploying Hadoop clusters. After a bit of tinkering you should be able to figure out the optimal cluster size for your problem.

Higher level services provided by AWS are great, and can save you a lot of time.